# c# forms program add http add urlacl

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, owin

I have a C# Windows Form program which runs a self hosting api.
I currently have to manually run the command

```
http add urlacl url=http://*:8888/ user=Users listen=yes
```

In an administrator cmd prompt.

I would like to automatically add this when the program is run. 
I have found a couple of answers which just point to the HttpSetServiceConfiguration function MS documentation but unfortunately
there are no sample lines of code which show how to run this command as c#.

Also I would like to add a firewall port programatically too which also requires to be run manually i.e.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="my local server" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8888
```

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run external programs as Administrator by using System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo with the "runas" verb.  If user access control (UAC) is enabled then Windows may halt execution of the program while it asks the user whether the action should be allowed or not.  If the current user does not have Admin rights then they must provide account credentials to an Administrator account before the action will be allowed, at which point the program you're trying to execute will resume.

The code to launch a process as Administrator looks something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

...

static void DoNetshStuff() {
    // get full path to netsh.exe command
    var netsh = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),
        "netsh.exe");

    // prepare to launch netsh.exe process
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(netsh);
    startInfo.Arguments = "http add urlacl url=http://*:8888/ user=Users listen=yes";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";

    try
    {
        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException)
    {
        // netsh.exe was missing?
    }
    catch(Win32Exception)
    {
        // user may have aborted the action, or doesn't have access
    }
}
```